# C++ Qt: QStyledItemDelegate's createEditor is never called, although paint() is called

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qt5, qitemdelegate

I have a `QListView` where I'd like to display a simple widget with a progress bar and some other fields (and some context menu, maybe, but currently I just want to display the widget). The list has a model under it, and the model successfully delivers a string to the list and everything works fine without the delegate.

Now with the delegate, the `createEditor()` method is *never* called. I don't understand why. I don't need to paint, but I just overrode `paint()` and `sizeHint()` to see whether they're called, and they are.

What I see on the `QListView` is basically the simple text items. The widget never shows up (of course, since `createEditor()` is never invoked).

The following is my delegate... quite basic!

```
class FileQueueItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FileQueueItemDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,
                              const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                              const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const override;
};
```

And the source (also quite basic and minimal):

```
#include "FileQueueItemDelegate.h"

FileQueueItemDelegate::FileQueueItemDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{

}

QWidget *FileQueueItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    std::cout<<"Creating editor..."<<std::endl;
    FileQueueListItem* item = new FileQueueListItem(parent);
    return item;
}

void FileQueueItemDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    std::cout<<"Setting editor data..."<<std::endl;
    FileQueueListItem* editorPtr = dynamic_cast<FileQueueListItem*>(editor);
    QVariant dataResult = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole);
    editorPtr->setFilename(dataResult.toString());
}

void FileQueueItemDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    std::cout<<"Setting model data..."<<std::endl;
}

void FileQueueItemDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    std::cout<<"Updating editor geometry..."<<std::endl;
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}

void FileQueueItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    std::cout<<"Painting..."<<std::endl;
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}

QSize FileQueueItemDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    std::cout<<"Size hint..."<<std::endl;
    return QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index);
}
```

I can see the prints of `paint()` and `sizeHint()`, but not the others (ever).

The following is the constructor of my `QListView` class (I inherited it from it):

```
FilesQueueQList::FilesQueueQList(FilesQueue* queueObjectPtr)
{
    this->internal_queue = queueObjectPtr;
    this->setModel(internal_queue); 
    itemDelegate = new FileQueueItemDelegate(this);
    this->setItemDelegate(itemDelegate);
}
```

And the following is its definition:

```
class FilesQueueQList : public QListView
{
    Q_OBJECT
    FilesQueue* internal_queue; //this inherits from QAbstractListModel
    FileQueueItemDelegate* itemDelegate;

//...
}
```

And finally, this is the `data()` method in the model:

```
QVariant FilesQueue::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    std::cout<<"Loading data of "<<index.row()<< " "<<index.column()<<std::endl;
    if ( role == Qt::DisplayRole ) {
        return filesQueue[index.row()]->getFilename();
    }
    if(role == Qt::EditRole) {
        return filesQueue[index.row()]->getFilename(); //QString this is
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

Please assist. Let me know if you need more info. I've been trying a whole day to get this to work without any success. All I want is to get that widget (`FileQueueListItem`) to be displayed on the list.

Comment: The `createEditor` member is only called when something happens to trigger editing of an item in the view.  What are the [edit triggers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop) associated with your view?

Comment: @G.M. The answer down there helped, however, there's still a part missing there. Could you look into as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not implemented `FilesQueue::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const`.
Default implementation makes cells only enabled and selectable.

See documentation: [QAbstractItemModel::flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags)

> #### [Qt::ItemFlags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) QAbstractItemModel::flags(const [QModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html) &*index*) const
>
> Returns the item flags for the given *index*.
>
> The base class implementation returns a combination of flags that enables the item (`ItemIsEnabled`) and allows it to be selected (`ItemIsSelectable`).

Comment: You're right! Thank you for the hint. However, the widget doesn't show up until I double-click the item element for it to "change" into that widget. Even when it changes, it still preserves the initial list item (that is only text). Any idea?